# Create global keyboard shortcut to delete entire line on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I've grown accustomed to pressing Cmd-D to delete the entire line of text that I'm editing in Eclipse.

I can't seem to find a way to add this command to other Mac programs. Can this be done?

I do know about Cmd-Backspace and Ctrl-K but I want to delete the entire line, regardless of the position of the cursor and including the CR/LF at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create or modify `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "$\U007F" = (selectParagraph:, delete:); // $\U007F = shift-delete
}
```

The changes will be applied after reopening apps or logging out and back in. Custom keybindings don't work in some cross platform applications (like Eclipse, Netbeans, 
Firefox and Photoshop), but they do in most native ones.

- [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html)
- [KeyBindings - Lri.me](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/lranta/keybindings/)
- [KeyBinding madness - Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/keybinding-madness/)

Comment: The delete portion of this isn't triggering in Sublime Text for whatever reason.

Comment: Update: Had to use `deleteBackward` or `deleteForward` instead.

Comment: For me the following worked for me across most applications: `"@d" = (deleteLine:);`